# How to convert a WinForm GUI to PowerShell script?

Tags: winforms, forms, user-interface, powershell, converters

As we know, we can [write a PowerShell script to show a windows form](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_GUIs_in_Windows_PowerShell_1.0_with_WinForms#A_Basic_Windows_PowerShell_GUI).

Is there a automatic converter that converts a WinForm assembly or *.designer.cs (designer generated C# code) into PowerShell script?

There was a "PrimalForms 2011" community version, but it seems that it's now called "PowerShell Studio 2012" and has a 45 days trail version.

Is there another choice? A simpler converter or something?
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better choice to keep your WinForm and run your script from it? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18229/How-to-run-PowerShell-scripts-from-C

Comment: but I want to generate PS code to show a WinForm like this:
 $form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
 $form1.Controls.Add($textboxNumber1)
 $form1.Controls.Add($buttonOK)
 $form1.ClientSize = '355, 116'
 $form1.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedDialog'
 $form1.MaximizeBox = $False
 $buttonOK_Click={
  $textboxResult.Text = [int]$textboxNumber1.Text + [int]$textboxNumber2.Text
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I steel use two solutions (well hidden on the web but still existing) to solve your problem :

**First**, You can use [Sapiens PrimalForms Community Edition](http://www.sapien.com/downloads#Community%20Tools/32%20Bit/PrimalFormsCE.exe) (It's free, you just have to sign to Sapiens and go to download).This Framwork allow you to graphicaly build your DialogBox and then it generates the PowerShell Code for Windows Forms (still avalaible as shown here under).

[image]

**Second** you've got a script called [PowerShell Form Converter](http://powershell-scripting.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=134&Itemid=71) writen by Arnaud Petitjean (11-05-2007). Once again you have to register, the article is writen in french, but you can download a Powershell script that transform a Windows Form from a .CS file to a PS1. Like in Sapiens editor, the transformation is commented (here in french) with the place to code events.